# How to organize parsed data into tables using command prompt?

Tags: command-prompt

I am attempting to create a table in excel that reads folder directories as field headers and lists contents as row data. I am trying to parse through existing work section folders that contain training certificates of staff and compile a list of them into a table.

REM cd /This is my workspace directory to organize into a table

dir /s *cert1 /b /o:gn >query.csv & dir /s *cert2 /b /o:gn >>query.csv

This creates an output, but its still messy and hard to sort. I would like to delineate the tables by folder but I cant find a simple way of doing it in command prompt.

Comment: it is not clear how the directory tree is structured, where the data is and what it is. Add more information with an example of what you want to have.

Comment: Sorry about that. The folder directory I want to parse is as follows: /Main_Directory/Section/Person1/person_Certificate.pdf. I was trying to get a list of each persons certificates so I can determine who has completed required training and uploaded their certificates. I also dont need the entire path returned, but I dont know how to only return the contents of a directory.

Comment: I'll help you, you have to update the question with the information you need so it is clearer and it will surely take less time to resolve the issue. I know excel quite well, maybe pivot tables could be useful to you. In that case we organize ourselves to build the data for the pivot table. Otherwise we make a simple table. Can you give me an example of how you want to organize the excel table?

Comment: I wanted to basically run a query on the staffs training certificates every quarter to check completion status. Because of this, I was hoping to make it as automatic as possible. I know that I can easily create the tables in excel but I wanted to reduce the amount of processing required. Essentially, run a query on staff folders and have a chart or graph that depicts training status and/or gaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code use **relative path**. You can change in absolute adding the "\" in the beginning of the MyPath variable.

`set "MyPath=Main_Directory\Section"`

change in:

`set "MyPath=\Main_Directory\Section"`

---

**make_table_csv.cmd**:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "MyPath=Main_Directory\Section"

set "header="
For /f %%F in ('dir /b %MyPath%') do if not defined header (set header="%%~F") else (set header=!header!,"%%~F")

echo %header%

set /A C=0, MaxR=0
For /f %%F in ('dir /b %MyPath%') do (
  Set /A R=1,C+=1  
  For /f %%G in ('dir /b %MyPath%\%%F') do set M[!R!,!C!]=%%G & set /A R+=1
  if !R! GTR !MaxR! set /A MaxR=!R!-1
)

rem echo %MaxR% %C%

For /L %%R in (1,1,%MaxR%) do (
  set "Row="
  For /L %%C in (1,1,%C%) do if not defined Row (set Row="!M[%%R,%%C]!") else (set Row=!Row!,"!M[%%R,%%C]!")
  echo !Row!
)
```

Copy this code, for example, in "make_table_csv.cmd"

execute the batch file and see the output:

```
C:\Users\fposc\AppData\Local\Temp>make_table_csv.cmd
"Person1","Person10","Person11","Person12","Person13","Person14","Person15","Person2","Person3","Person4","Person5","Person6","Person7","Person8","Person9"
"person_Certificate1.pdf ","person_Certificate1.pdf ","person_Certificate1.pdf ","person_Certificate1.pdf ","person_Certificate1.pdf ","person_Certificate1.pdf ","person_Certificate1.pdf ","person_Certificate1.pdf ","person_Certificate1.pdf ","person_Certificate1.pdf ","","person_Certificate1.pdf ","","person_Certificate1.pdf ",""
"person_Certificate2.pdf ","person_Certificate2.pdf ","","person_Certificate2.pdf ","person_Certificate2.pdf ","","person_Certificate2.pdf ","person_Certificate2.pdf ","person_Certificate2.pdf ","person_Certificate2.pdf ","","person_Certificate2.pdf ","","",""
"person_Certificate3.pdf ","person_Certificate3.pdf ","","person_Certificate3.pdf ","person_Certificate3.pdf ","","person_Certificate3.pdf ","person_Certificate3.pdf ","person_Certificate3.pdf ","person_Certificate3.pdf ","","person_Certificate3.pdf ","","",""
"person_Certificate4.pdf ","","","person_Certificate4.pdf ","person_Certificate4.pdf ","","person_Certificate4.pdf ","","","","","person_Certificate4.pdf ","","",""
"person_Certificate5.pdf ","","","","person_Certificate5.pdf ","","","","","","","person_Certificate5.pdf ","","",""

C:\Users\fposc\AppData\Local\Temp>
```

you can make a "csv" file with:

`make_table_csv.cmd > table.csv`

then you can import "table.csv" in excel or create a link to it in excel.

*if you need changes, please ask in the comments.*

Comment: I found a sort of solution that gets me by for the short term using excel formulas and some simple enough data normalization. Im going to try your recommendation, but I think that looks exactly like what I am trying. Thanks for the help!